# Clion 2019.2 в linux mint 19.2, не компилируется хеллоуворлд на си

Tags: linux, c, gcc, linux-mint, clion

Перед установкой Clion я проверил наличие gcc, установил cmake и gdb. Clion при установке автоматически нашёл usr/bin/cc, нашёл смаке и gdb. Я попробовал скомпилировать хеллоуворлд - не получилось. Потом попробовал сделать это с помощью текстового редактора и терминала, опять не получилось. Далее я установил libc6-dev. Написал хеллоуворлд в текстовом редакторе, скомпилировал и запустил с помощью терминала. Всё прошло нормально. Но Clion скомпилировать данную программу не смог. Вот такой он выдал мне вывод:

> /snap/clion/92/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" /home/krogan/CLionProjects/untitled
>
> -- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
>
> -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
>
> -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- broken
>
> CMake Error at /snap/clion/92/bin/cmake/linux/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:60 (message):
>
> The C compiler
>
> "/usr/bin/cc"
>
> is not able to compile a simple test program.
>
> It fails with the following output:
>
> Change Dir: /home/krogan/CLionProjects/untitled/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_5e310/fast && /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_5e310.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_5e310.dir/build
>       make[1]: вход в каталог «/home/krogan/CLionProjects/untitled/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp»
>       Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_5e310.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
>       /usr/bin/cc    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_5e310.dir/testCCompiler.c.o   -c /home/krogan/CLionProjects/untitled/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
>       Linking C executable cmTC_5e310
>       /snap/clion/92/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_5e310.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
>       /usr/bin/cc      CMakeFiles/cmTC_5e310.dir/testCCompiler.c.o  -o cmTC_5e310 
>       /usr/bin/ld: cannot find Scrt1.o: Нет такого файла или каталога
>       /usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: Нет такого файла или каталога
>       collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>       CMakeFiles/cmTC_5e310.dir/build.make:86: recipe for target 'cmTC_5e310' failed
>       make[1]:  [cmTC_5e310] Error 1
>       make[1]: выход из каталога «/home/krogan/CLionProjects/untitled/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp»
>       Makefile:121: recipe for target 'cmTC_5e310/fast' failed
>       make:  [cmTC_5e310/fast] Error 2
>
> CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
>   Call Stack (most recent call first):
>     CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
>   See also "/home/krogan/CLionProjects/untitled/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
>   See also "/home/krogan/CLionProjects/untitled/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
>
> [Previous CMake output restored: 21.11.2019, 12:05]

Чего ещё не хватает?

Comment: File/Settings.../Build, Execution, Deployment/CMake/  В окне Build Type стоял Debug. Я поставил Default и как мне кажется всё заработало, даже когда я вновь вернул данную настройку на Debug. Не уверен что это является полным решением проблемы

Comment: а вы Cmake проект конфигурировали? cmake . там, Почитайте Ваш CMakeLists.txt и вывод cmake внимательнее